# Oracle Sql: How to add multi sub total in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, subtotal

I want query multi sub total in query sql. How query multi sub total.
please help me.

**SQL CODE:**

```
SELECT MB.COUNTRY_CODE As C_CODE,
       MB.OPERATOR_NAME AS C_NAME,
       C.PMN_CODE AS OPER_NAME,
       (C.RANG_START / 1024) AS R_START,
       (C.RANG_END / 1024) AS R_END,
       COUNT(*) AS T_OPER,
       '0' AS TE_CHARGE,
       SUM(C.RATE) AS TR_CHARGE       
  FROM IR_V_IMM_RATE_BY_CDR C 
  LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_MASTER_BROKER MB ON C.COMPANY_CODE = MB.COMPANY_CODE 
   AND C.PMN_DOMAIN = MB.PMN_CODE
  LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_INTER_SERVICE S ON C.PMN_DOMAIN = S.PMN_CODE 
   AND C.COMPANY_CODE = S.COMPANY_CODE
  WHERE C.SUB_EVENT_TYPE_ID = '2'
   AND C.MODIFIER = 'P1P'
   AND S.INTER_SERVICE = 'MSS'
   AND C.COMPANY_CODE = 'ASS'
   AND C.EVENT_TYPE_ID = '622'
   AND C.PMN_DOMAIN = 'ACN'
   AND TO_CHAR(C.CUTOFF_DATE, 'MM/YYYY') = '04/2015'
  GROUP BY MB.COUNTRY_CODE, MB.OPERATOR_NAME, C.PMN_CODE, C.RANG_START, C.RANG_END, C.RATE
```

Result Query:

```
    C_CODE | C_NAME | OPER_NAME | R_START | R_END | T_OPER | TE_CHARGE | TR_CHARGE
    1      | Aic Ltd| AA        | 1       | 10    | 1      | 0         | 0.8324
    1      | Aic Ltd| AA        | 3       | 22    | 5      | 0         | 2.312931                                                                                    
    1      | Aic Ltd| BB        | 4       | 20    | 2      | 0         | 10    
    1      | Aic Ltd| BB        | 1       | 13    | 1      | 0         | 25
```

But i want add multi sub total in query.

**I want Result Query:**

```
C_CODE | C_NAME | OPER_NAME | R_START | R_END | T_OPER | TE_CHARGE | TR_CHARGE
1      | Aic Ltd| AA        | 1       | 10    | 1      | 0         | 0.8324
1      | Aic Ltd| AA        | 3       | 22    | 5      | 0         | 2.312931
                | Total                       | 6      | 0         | 3.145331
------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                    
1      | Aic Ltd| BB        | 4       | 20    | 2      | 0         | 10    
1      | Aic Ltd| BB        | 1       | 13    | 1      | 0         | 25
                | Total                       | 3      | 0         | 35
------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Total                                         | 9      | 0         | 38.145331
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
6      | SRI    | CC        | 2       | 11    | 2      | 0         | 1
6      | SRI    | CC        | 4       | 21    | 1      | 0         | 5
                | Total                       | 3      | 0         | 6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6      | SRI    | DD        | 5       | 30    | 1      | 0         | 1.21
6      | SRI    | DD        | 2       | 40    | 1      | 0         | 2.35
                | Total                       | 2      | 0         | 5.42
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                         | 5      | 0         | 11.42
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How add multi row sub total? Help me please.

Thanks in advance. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post a solution with using the [group by rollup extension](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm#DWHSG8608). Please try this.

```
with Src as (
select  1 C_CODE, 'Aic Ltd' C_NAME, 'AA' OPER_NAME, 1 R_START, 10 R_END, 1 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 0.8324 TR_CHARGE from dual union all
select  1 C_CODE, 'Aic Ltd' C_NAME, 'AA' OPER_NAME, 3 R_START, 22 R_END, 5 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 2.312931 TR_CHARGE from dual union all

select  1 C_CODE, 'Aic Ltd' C_NAME, 'BB' OPER_NAME, 4 R_START, 20 R_END, 2 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 10 TR_CHARGE from dual union all
select  1 C_CODE, 'Aic Ltd' C_NAME, 'BB' OPER_NAME, 1 R_START, 13 R_END, 1 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 25 TR_CHARGE from dual union all

select  6 C_CODE, 'SRI' C_NAME, 'CC' OPER_NAME, 2 R_START, 11 R_END, 2 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 1 TR_CHARGE from dual union all
select  6 C_CODE, 'SRI' C_NAME, 'CC' OPER_NAME, 4 R_START, 21 R_END, 1 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 5 TR_CHARGE from dual union all

select  6 C_CODE, 'SRI' C_NAME, 'DD' OPER_NAME, 5 R_START, 30 R_END, 1 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 1.21 TR_CHARGE from dual union all
select  6 C_CODE, 'SRI' C_NAME, 'DD' OPER_NAME, 2 R_START, 40 R_END, 1 T_OPER, 0 TE_CHARGE, 2.35 TR_CHARGE from dual
)

select c_code, c_name, oper_name, r_start, R_End, sum(T_OPER), sum(TE_CHARGE),
       sum(tr_charge)
  from src
 group by rollup(c_code, c_name, oper_name, r_start, R_End)
having grouping(c_name) = 0 and (grouping(r_Start) = 1 or grouping(R_End) = 1)
```

Though I think the answer provided [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) pointed out is also very good answer and suggestion to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you want is provided using extensions to `GROUP BY`.  Because you only want some subtotals, `GROUPING SETS` is appropriate.

```
GROUP BY GROUPING_SETS((MB.COUNTRY_CODE, MB.OPERATOR_NAME, C.PMN_CODE, C.RANG_START, C.RANG_END, C.RATE),
                       (MB.COUNTRY_CODE, MB.OPERATOR_NAME, C.PMN_CODE),
                       ())
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/aggreg.htm#i1006842).

To get values such as `'Total'` in the `Oper_Name` column, you need to identify the additional aggregation rows.  Oracle provides the function `GROUPING()` for this:

```
(CASE WHEN GROUPING(C.PMN_CODE) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE C.PMN_CODE
 END) as Oper_Name
```

Comment: Error ORA 00907: this line .GROUPING_SETS((MB.COUNTRY_CODE